FastAPI Why i get Unsupported upgrade request with DELETE request?
I have written a fastapi backend.
To keep the code clean I wanted to uninstall everything that was installed via pip during development and then only install the most necessary. After I did that, one endpoint doesn't seem to work anymore.
One of the endpoints worked perfectly before. Now problems arise. Using curl or the FastAPI's /docs page the endpoint seems to work, but when my other Java service accesses FastAPI I get the following error:
WARNING:  Unsupported upgrade request.
WARNING:  No supported WebSocket library detected. Please use "pip install 'uvicorn[standard]'", or install 'websockets' or 'wsproto' manually.
INFO:     127.0.0.1:52852 - "DELETE /delete-file/ HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity

uvicorn is already installed and I don't use a websocket.
I have output the request body in java:
2024-07-15 19:15:14 Request Body: {"host":"http://localhost:9200","index":"rag-embeddings","fileEntryId":41818}

And I get the following error message in java:
2024-07-15 19:15:14 Failed to delete file entry: {"detail":[{"type":"missing","loc":["body"],"msg":"Field required","input":null}]}

Here is the endpoint:
class Metadata(BaseModel):
    host: str
    index: str
    fileEntryId: int


@app.delete("/delete-file/")
async def delete_file(request: Metadata):
    print(f"Received request: {request}")
    ...

Here are the package Versions:
uvicorn==0.30.1
fastapi==0.110.2
fastapi-cli==0.0.4
pydantic==2.7.1
pydantic_core==2.18.2

I tried to uninstall uvicorn and install 'uvicorn[standard]' but the problem stays the same.

I've tried to run the code you provided and it works fine! I assume that Request Body printed is not a request body, but something else. Please double check this moment.

You can actually implement a dummy endpoint for debugging purposes to be able to print everything about a request: body, headers, etc.

Sorry, how do you start the server? Could you please print the command. Also how do you call the delete method from the client side?

I'm not sure that the issue is with the delete method. Most probably warning related to other methods that wait for socket connections. Here is reproducible example:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class Metadata(BaseModel):
    host: str
    index: str
    fileEntryId: int

@app.delete("/delete-file")
async def delete_file(request: Metadata):
    print(f"Received request: {request}")

run the server with:
uvicorn app:app

Run the client with:
import requests

data = {
    "host": '23423',
    "index": "geek",
    "fileEntryId": 3
}

requests.delete("http://localhost:8000/delete-file", 
                json=data)

Outputs:
INFO:     Started server process [91789]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Received request: host='23423' index='geek' fileEntryId=3
INFO:     127.0.0.1:64390 - "DELETE /delete-file HTTP/1.1" 200 OK

As you can see there is nothing related to websockets upgrade.
However, in any case it is worth installing websockets with pip as it is suggested in the warning message, it wouldn't harm the project. Run:
pip install websockets

